# Selected categories not showing in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm learning how to make Django websites, simple for now. It is necessary that the category of each account is displayed through the p tag, and all through the rest a. Following the results of all categories are links [How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WD1kw.png)
[As a result is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGn3L.png)

tags.py

```
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_category(filter=None):
    if not filter:
        return Category.objects.all()
    else:
        return Category.objects.filter(slug_fields=filter)

@register.simple_tag(name="hypixel_accaunts")
def get_accaunt():
    return hypixel.objects.all()


@register.inclusion_tag('product/hyp_cats.html')
def show_category(sort=None, cat_selected=0):
    if not sort:
        category = Category.objects.all()
    else:
        category = Category.objects.order_by(sort)
    return {'category': category, 'cat_selected' : cat_selected}
```

From hyp_cats.html

```
{% for c in category %}
    {% if c.slug_fields  == cat_selected %}
        <p>{{ c.name }}</p>
    {% else %}
        <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.name }} </a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

From main templates

```
    {% get_category as get_cats %}
    {% if cat_selected == 0 %}
        <p>All accaunts</p>
    {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'hype' %}">All accaunts</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% show_category '-name' cat_selected %}
    <br>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
```

From views.py

```
def show_acc(request, acc_id):
    accaunt = get_object_or_404(hypixel, nickname=acc_id)
    contex = {
        'accaunt': accaunt,
        'cat_selected' : accaunt.cat,
    }
    return render(request,'product/hype_accaunt.html', context=contex)
```

From models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True)
    slug_fields = models.SlugField(max_length=255,unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name="URL")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('cats', kwargs ={'cat_id' : self.slug_fields})
```

If you need more parts of the code, then write

The essence of the site is to display accounts from databases, each of the accounts has categories, the category of the account depends on its donation. When you enter the page of the selected account, its characteristics are displayed, menus with all possible categories are displayed at the top left, they are made as links, however, if an account with the 'VIP' category is selected, in this menu the 'VIP' category will be displayed through the p tag, and not through a like the others.